# Implementing Linear Regression in ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, linear-regression

I was supposed to develop a web application that also includes predicting an expected arrival date of parcel value based on the origin location of the value, and I was thinking of using Linear Regression model. Though I'm not sure if this is feasible: implementing linear regression in web application. I can't seem to find any suitable resources on this for beginners on linear regression in web application. Please provide any thoughts or resources if anyone has any.

Comment: These two are not necessarily related. You just implemented the Linear Regression somehow and then you create a web-based interface

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with? What makes you think it would be infeasible? And as the above mentions, the web application part is only relevant when you come to display the results. The calculation could be done in c# to be re-used in any type of application. Your question is very vague and it's unclear what you want from us. Also, asking for links to resources is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: My apologies. I should've phrased my question clearer. I am trying to implement linear regression in a web application and I am now aware it can be done in c#, or any language as long as the logic is there. However, I am not familiar how that can be done, like the algorithm or methods of it as some of the resources I see online are confusing and difficult. So I was wondering if I could get some advices here for beginners.

Comment: We're not a mathematics site who would teach you about the actual calculations involved. It _is_ moderately complex maths I think. We could help you with a _specific_ question about making an implementation in c# though, if you had one. I'm surprised maybe no-one had already written such a thing - did you search for any existing tools / libraries in .NET?

Comment: Maybe something like https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/regression-analysis/find-a-linear-regression-equation/ would help with the concepts

Comment: As for c#, maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/test-run-linear-regression-using-csharp . But I don't know, it's hard to judge your exact level of knowledge. Perhaps if you are a complete beginner to c# and/or not experienced with mathematics then this might not be the best topic for your project, unless you can find a ready-made library that doesn't require you to understand anything about the statistical calculations in order to use it